# Выбрать 2 слова до выделенного фрагмента и два после

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я делаю скрипт нажмите `CTRL+ENTER` чтоб сообщить об ошибке. Все нормально, все работает.

Но задача такая: Выбрать еще 2 слова до полученного в переменную `text` и два слова после. Если бы все было в одних и тех же тегах, например `p`
то я знаю как сделать. Я бы нашел родителя у этого текста, типа так `$('p:contains(text)')`, преобразовал бы в массив, потом взял бы 2 значения до теста и 2 после, с этим все понятно.

Но я не знаю в каких элементах будет этот текст. он может быть и в `li` и в `b`
и в чем угодно, в `h1` например или `blockquote`.

`$('*:contains(text)')` не помогает, потому что находит все начиная с `body`
мол и там и там и там оно содержится.

В общем то мне надо только узнать, как найти родителя определенного текста (там одно 2 10 слов может быть), дальше я разберусь. Желательно на jquery.

В общем после некоторых комментариев уважаемых пользователей, я понял что не правильно сформулировал вопрос. много воды...
Правильно наверное так - Как узнать в каком элементе содержится определенный текст, если я не знаю что это за элемент p li h1 или еще что то.

Comment: Что в случае такового нет? Если всего 1 слово

Comment: Не решение, но как вариант вы можете брать селектор элемента (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42184417/11929476) и индекс начала текста, тогда найти место ошибки будет весьма просто без окружающих слов. Так можно будет даже подсвечивать элемент по селектору при нахождении.

Comment: действительно, а зачем вам 2 слова до выделенного? Если для нахождения на странице, тогда действительно лучше сохранить селектор элемента.

Comment: дак откуда же я знаю зачем))) заказчик где то такое увидел и желает)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify куда-нить сюда может покопать? посмотрите таблицу совместимости, мб достаточного этого будет

Comment: какой-нить бы так `llrr'.split('').forEach(d => sel.modify('extend', dirs[d], 'word' ))` но не работает.